# Folder missing in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs

We have a folder that we branched from recently:

$/Care/Code/CareSys Desktop/CareSys-R5

However, it appears that this folder has gone missing in the TFS Source Control explorer. It has not been renamed. It has not been moved. It has not been deleted - I have used the "show deleted items" (X) function, and the folder still doesn't show.

Using the tf.exe tool, running "tf.exe changeset 10231 /collection:[url snipped out as irrelevant]" I can see a commit against the folder, so it exists - somewhere.

How can I get this folder to show in TFS?

Comment: Could your mate see this specific  branch on TFS server?

Comment: Hi Patrick, me and my colleague can't see the branch at all.  Could it be security setting related that the folder isn't shown? TFS Security settings were changed yesterday, because previous settings were allowing the devs to do too much. I had a look at the new settings and they look perfectly valid. Don't see why this single folder and its subfolders would be hidden though.

Comment: What does 'tf history <folderpathandname>' show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your info, it seems related to the security settings. You can also use `tf history <folderpathandname>` to display the revision history of that folder as *allen* suggested. To see the 'hidden' folder. you must have **read** permission of that folder.

You can use [tf permission command](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/permission-command) to list all permission such as `tf permission /server:<servername> <folder path in TFS>`

*Note: To use the permission command, you must have the Manipulate security settings permission set to Allow for the folders being modified, be a member of the Team Foundation Administrators security group, or be a system administrator on the local computer (Windows Administrator security group).*

Comment: From tf permission I found that the "Contributors" group had "deny" on the folder, and this was preventing the developers from seeing the folder. Thanks for your help, you are a lifesaver!!!! :)

Comment: The command line I ran to fix the issue was like so: tf permission /allow:read /group:[Care]\Contributors /collection:"http://mstfs1:8080/tfs/[removed]" "$/Care/Code/CareSys Desktop/CareSys-R5"